# HTML 5 Alignment of text with content html messy code

Tags: html

Please be kind, i'm just starting the basic web dev course and my question is about `html5` in nature.

HI i was wondering if there was a solution to this?
[Live Preview of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J2nn.png)

I have an image aligned left and an `<iframe>` embed in the right. I've placed both on diff `<p>` but all seemed to line up. Even my text. My noob solution was to do a multiple `<br>` to get my text down.  This is my code:

```html
<hr>
        <p>     <img src="Federer%20Page.jpeg" width="500" height="300" align="left"> </p>
        
        <p>
                <iframe align="right" width="500" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/La0K68TsN4E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
        
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>      
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
        
        
        
                
                
        <p>
            <h1> Roger Federer</h1>
            <h2> "Swiss Maestro"</h2>
        </p>
```

Is this a code problem? Or is it something that `css` fixes?

Would appreciate any master's help. I am seeking to get the pebble from your hands.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please share your code...

Comment: Hi A. Meshu, i edited my question and added my photos!

Comment: @JoshuaMisajon Please don't post your code as photos. Use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Sorry bout that! How do i make a stack snippet?

Comment: @JoshuaMisajon https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: that was awesome man. Did just that! hope i got it right!

Comment: Hi @JoshuaMisajon, please reformat your code nicely with 4 or 2 spaces, and my advice is 2. You can read it on [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Hi Adi by 4 or 2 spaces you are referring to what specifically?

Answer (score 0):

[Line break elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) `<br>` are not really designed to create spacing around elements. That being said, you'll likely see them being used in examples, tutorials and maybe even on some production websites.

A `<br>` element is designed to add line breaks inside paragraphs of text. Like this:

```
<p>Hello there!<br>Nice to meet you</p>
```

When you need spacing around elements, use the CSS [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property. Like this:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Amazing_Roger_Federer.jpg" width="500" height="300">

<div class="info">
  <h1> Roger Federer</h1>
  <h2> "Swiss Maestro"</h2>
</div>
```

This basic example adds some bottom margin below the `<img>` element. It's worth noting that properties like `margin` work only on block-level elements (an image element is inline by default). For the example to work I had to convert it to a block level element using CSS.

Tip: When you need to group many elements use a generic container `<div>` element. Instead of a `<p>` element.

Take a look at MDN's great [Learn web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) section to learn more.

Additional resources:

- [Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: Thank you Juan marco. So as i thought, to make the code cleaner the solution is of CSS in nature rather than forcing the html code show me the result i was looking for yes?